# ReactJS not rendering real-time graphs with MuPlot as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

TLDR: ReactJS not rendering graphs as expected like in JavaScript :(

Hello everyone,

I am currently working on a project that requires real-time rendering of Line graphs using MuPlot in ReactJS. The graph should render a large amount of data points quickly, as I am building something similar to a heartbeat monitor for a surgeon in a surgery room. The surgeon needs to be able to view a lot of data at once, so it's important that the graph updates quickly.

I am trying to create a simple project to test if this can be done using ReactJS and the JavaScript ecosystem. I need to have a line of null values visible to the surgeon to indicate where the latest samples are (like an empty vertical line that moves from left to right).
[image]

[image]
I have successfully created a working example of the graph using plain JavaScript (examples provided below

- [example1](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/focused-spence-ckfgjr?file=%2Fpublic%2Findex.html&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A1%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A216%2C%22startColumn%22%3A1%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A216%7D%5D)
- [example2](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/new-paper-1zpjy8?file=%2Fpublic%2Fdist%2FuPlot.esm.js&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A1%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A73%2C%22startColumn%22%3A1%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A73%7D%5D))

, but I am having trouble replicating the same functionality in ReactJS.

**I have tried two different methods in ReactJS, one using a local variable and one using a file, but only the local variable approach is currently working. I have provided a link to my code and a screenshot of the current result for both methods.**

Here are the links to the working and non-working examples:

Working ReactJS example using a variable as data: [link3](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-graph-nulls-working-stackoverflow-z831tv?file=/src/App.js)

**Non-working ReactJS example using a file:**

- [Github link](https://github.com/dolev146/react-muplot-jsonfileexample/blob/main/src/App.jsx)
- [deployed link](https://react-muplot-jsonfileexample.vercel.app/)

**sorry i cant give for that codesandbox, the json file doing me problems**

Can anyone help me understand why the ReactJS code is not working with a file and how to fix it?

Also, if anyone has any tips or suggestions for real-time graphs or the best tools for the job, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you in advance for your help!